# Nice derivation of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^n}+\frac{\bar q^{2n}}{1-\bar q^n}\right)=-\sum_{m=2}^\infty \ln |1-q^m|^2$

Tags: summation

I'm searching for a nice derivation of the formua

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^n}+\frac{\bar q^{2n}}{1-\bar q^n}\right)=-\sum_{m=2}^\infty \ln |1-q^m|^2$

given for example in http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0804.1773 eq.(4.27).

Comment: It suffices to show only the holomorphic part: $\sum_n \frac1n \frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^n}=-\sum_m \ln \left(1-q^m\right)$. Why not simply expand the geometric series on the left, the logarithm on the right and compare the coefficients of different powers of $q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the double sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^\infty q^{n(m+2)}
=  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} q^{n(m+2)} = \sum_{m=\color{red}{\mathbf{2}}}^\infty \log (1 - q^{m}) $$

This is a physics paper.  They aren't worried that both sides diverge if $q^n=1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Did you notice earlier in the paper this was written in exponential form?

$$ Z = \mathrm{exp}\bigg[ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} \frac{q^{2n}}{1-q^n} \bigg] = \prod_{m \geq 2} \frac{1}{1-q^m} = \mathrm{Tr}[q^{L_0}]$$

where $L_0$ is a generator of the [Virasoro algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra).

The original definition of $Z$ was a [functional determinant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21522/how-are-functional-determinants-of-laplace-type-operators-used-in-physics) of the Laplacian $\det \Delta$ in [Anti-De Sitter](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1206) space $\mathbb{H}^3/\mathbb{Z}$ (Section 4.1 in [arXiv:0804.1773v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1773v1.pdf))

Comment: Thx for the answer.

Comment: Cool stuff! The function $Z$ is almost the inverse of the [Dedekind eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).